# Difference Between Function and Predicate In Alloy 4?

Tags: alloy

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between predicates and functions in Alloy 4. I've read section 4.5.2 in Software Abstractions but it's still not clear to me. Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function simply represents a parameterized expression which gets inlined at every invocation site.

A predicate represents a formula, i.e., a boolean expression, so in that sense it is kind of like a function which returns a boolean expression.  Another difference is that in Alloy you can "run" and "check" predicates, using the Alloy "run" and "check" commands.  Running a predicate instructs Alloy to find a model for which that predicate holds, whereas checking a predicate instructs Alloy to check if there exists a model for which that predicate does not hold.